# What could prevent a custom url scheme from being registered in the Launch Services Database

Tags: macos, url-scheme

I have developed a software that launches from a custom url scheme (something like "myapp://123"). It works on two of my test Mac machines (running 10.7.3 and 10.8 respectively) but somehow it doesn't work on another machine running 10.7.3

Are there any system or security settings that disable custom url scheme, or anyway I could troubleshoot this problem? It seems not to be just a faulty launch service database setting as three Macs at the client side aren't unable to register the custom url scheme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the client's computer is running a version of Mac OS that is too low for the developed application. I guess step 1 is troubleshooting this problem is to make sure the application can run in the first place!